# Editing blank feature class in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, editing

I am very new to ArcGIS Desktop.

I have a jpeg showing an old map of NYC zones. I was able to georeference this image with a shapefile of NYC blocks. I wish to now create a new feature class where I can trace these zones from the old jpeg onto the new feature class layer using the blocks shapefile as a reference. I will also wish to trace along the blocks in that blocks shapefile layer.

I've been following [this thread's advice](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/19520-creating-and-saving-new-features-to-a-new-%28blank%29-layer) (second reply) so far. It is as follows:

> Add your empty feature class/shapefile to arcmap, and click your Editor button and go to Start Editing. (Assuming you are using V10?)
>
> If you plan on following existing geographic features, look at using the Trace tool.
>   Hint: When tracing, whatever feature you want your line to follow, it has to be Selected.
>
> There are several ways to select a feature:
>   ...by Location
>   ...by Attribute
>   ...by Graphic
>
> Try to explore the Feature Construction toolbar and the various segment creation tools.

However, after I create this blank feature class and add it as a layer, I cannot edit it! I go into "Start Editing" mode, choose the blank feature class, but I cannot trace or do anything after that.

Is there any hope for me?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a new feature template first before you can create any new feature classes (via tracing, etc.)  I believe this is new to version 10.  See http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/03/19/creating-and-using-feature-templates/  In short, if I remember correctly, from the editor menu you go to more winodws -> create features.  Then click "new" to make a new feature template.

Comment: After I create a feature template I can draw things but I'm not sure how to save them as a new layer. At this point I think I've rushed into something I wasn't prepared for. This all seems too complicated for me. Thank you for your help, though.

Answer (score 1):

I sympathise with this problem. This is something that ought to be very simple but is actually quite confusing in ArcGIS10.

When you say:

'I can draw things but I'm not sure how to save them as a new layer.'

It makes me think that you haven't created a new layer *first* for editing. For your task it sounds like you want to create a new layer first (I usually use catalogue). In catalogue right-click on the folder you want to work in and select 'Add new Shapefile Layer'.

Then do your tracing etc on this new layer.